# Compiling ruby1.9.1 hangs and fills swap

Tags: ruby, compilation, ubuntu-8.04

I'm compiling Ruby 1.9.1-p376 under Ubuntu 8.04 server LTS (64-bit), by doing the following:

```
$ ./configure
$ make
$ sudo make install
```

`./configure` works without complaints.

`make` hangs indefinitely until all my RAM and swap is gone. It get stuck after the following output:

```
compiling ripper
make[1]: Entering directory `/tmp/ruby1.9.1/ruby-1.9.1-p376/ext/ripper'
gcc -I. -I../../.ext/include/x86_64-linux -I../.././include -I../.././ext/ripper -I../.. -I../../. -DRUBY_EXTCONF_H=\"extconf.h\"    -fPIC  -O2 -g -Wall -Wno-parentheses  -o ripper.o -c ripper.c
```

If I run the `gcc` command by hand, with the `-v` argument to get verbose output, it hangs after the following:

```
Using built-in specs.
Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran,objc,obj-c++,treelang --prefix=/usr --enable-shared --with-system-zlib --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --enable-nls --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2 --program-suffix=-4.2 --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-objc-gc --enable-mpfr --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.2.4 (Ubuntu 4.2.4-1ubuntu4)
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.2.4/cc1 -quiet -v -I. -I../../.ext/include/x86_64-linux -I../.././include -I../.././ext/ripper -I../.. -I../../. -DRUBY_EXTCONF_H="extconf.h" ripper.c -quiet -dumpbase ripper.c -mtune=generic -auxbase-strip ripper.o -g -O2 -Wall -Wno-parentheses -version -fPIC -fstack-protector -fstack-protector -o /tmp/ccRzHvYH.s
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/local/include/x86_64-linux-gnu"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.2.4/../../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/include"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu"
ignoring duplicate directory "../.././ext/ripper"
ignoring duplicate directory "../../."
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 .
 ../../.ext/include/x86_64-linux
 ../.././include
 ../..
 /usr/local/include
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.2.4/include
 /usr/include
End of search list.
GNU C version 4.2.4 (Ubuntu 4.2.4-1ubuntu4) (x86_64-linux-gnu)
    compiled by GNU C version 4.2.4 (Ubuntu 4.2.4-1ubuntu4).
GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=47 --param ggc-min-heapsize=32795
Compiler executable checksum: 6e11fa7ca85fc28646173a91f2be2ea3
```

I just compiled ruby on another computer for reference, and it took about 10 seconds to print the following output (after the above `Compiler executable checksum` line):

```
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-I.' '-I../../.ext/include/i686-linux' '-I../.././include' '-I../.././ext/ripper' '-I../..' '-I../../.' '-DRUBY_EXTCONF_H="extconf.h"' '-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64' '-fPIC' '-O2' '-g' '-Wall' '-Wno-parentheses' '-o' 'ripper.o' '-c' '-mtune=generic' '-march=i486'
 as -V -Qy -o ripper.o /tmp/cca4fa7R.s
GNU assembler version 2.20 (i486-linux-gnu) using BFD version (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu) 2.20
COMPILER_PATH=/usr/lib/gcc/i486-linux-gnu/4.4.1/:/usr/lib/gcc/i486-linux-gnu/4.4.1/:/usr/lib/gcc/i486-linux-gnu/:/usr/lib/gcc/i486-linux-gnu/4.4.1/:/usr/lib/gcc/i486-linux-gnu/:/usr/lib/gcc/i486-linux-gnu/4.4.1/:/usr/lib/gcc/i486-linux-gnu/
LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/gcc/i486-linux-gnu/4.4.1/:/usr/lib/gcc/i486-linux-gnu/4.4.1/:/usr/lib/gcc/i486-linux-gnu/4.4.1/../../../../lib/:/lib/../lib/:/usr/lib/../lib/:/usr/lib/gcc/i486-linux-gnu/4.4.1/../../../:/lib/:/usr/lib/
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-I.' '-I../../.ext/include/i686-linux' '-I../.././include' '-I../.././ext/ripper' '-I../..' '-I../../.' '-DRUBY_EXTCONF_H="extconf.h"' '-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64' '-fPIC' '-O2' '-g' '-Wall' '-Wno-parentheses' '-o' 'ripper.o' '-c' '-mtune=generic' '-march=i486'
```

I have **absolutely** no clue what could be going wrong here - any ideas where I should start?

**Edit: fsck output**

```
$ sudo fsck -n
fsck 1.40.8 (13-Mar-2008)
e2fsck 1.40.8 (13-Mar-2008)
Warning!  /dev/sda1 is mounted.
Warning: skipping journal recovery because doing a read-only filesystem check.
/dev/sda1 contains a file system with errors, check forced.
Pass 1: Checking inodes, blocks, and sizes
Deleted inode 557058 has zero dtime.  Fix? no

Inodes that were part of a corrupted orphan linked list found.  Fix? no

Inode 557059 was part of the orphaned inode list.  IGNORED.
Inode 557060 was part of the orphaned inode list.  IGNORED.
Inode 557061 was part of the orphaned inode list.  IGNORED.
Inode 557062 was part of the orphaned inode list.  IGNORED.
Pass 2: Checking directory structure
Pass 3: Checking directory connectivity
Pass 4: Checking reference counts
Pass 5: Checking group summary information
Free blocks count wrong (2026992, counted=2014241).
Fix? no

Inode bitmap differences:  -(557058--557062)
Fix? no

Free inodes count wrong (1130174, counted=1129768).
Fix? no


/dev/sda1: ********** WARNING: Filesystem still has errors **********

/dev/sda1: 115010/1245184 files (0.7% non-contiguous), 463376/2490368 blocks
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -y install libc6-dev libssl-dev libmysql++-dev libsqlite3-dev make build-essential libssl-dev libreadline5-dev zlib1g-dev
```

Then try to install ruby again.

**EDIT:**

you can also try:

```
sudo apt-get install ruby1.9.1-full
```

or try a different revision of 1.9.1

```
wget ftp://ftp.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/1.9/ruby-1.9.1-p243.tar.gz
```

to see if it's your machine or the ruby code.

Comment: If building the project hangs because of missing dependencies I would recommend also filing a bug report.

Comment: No dice. I didn't have libmysql++-dev or libreadline5-dev, but I installed them and tried recompiling and had the same problem: compilation hung at `ripper.o` and filled up my swap.

Comment: Can you try running make with MAKEOPTS=-j1

Comment: Tried adding `MAKEOPTS=-j1` to the top of my `Makefile` and had the exact same behaviour. I also tried running `export MAKEOPTS="-j1" ; make`. Is one of those the correct way to set the option?

Comment: Can't install package `ruby1.9.1-full` as I'm still on 8.04 LTS and it's not backported in the package archives. Will try compiling a previous version of 1.9.1 now.

Comment: `ruby-1.9.1-p243` compiled correctly. Does anyone have any idea why `p376` would be failing at `ripper`??

Comment: Ok, while this *is* a workaround, I've marked it as the correct answer as it has solved my problem. I compiled `ruby-1.9.1-p243` from source without error.

Answer (score 1):

Had the exact same problem on my system (Ubuntu 8.04) when compiling ruby-1.9.1-p378. I went back to an earlier version of ruby (**ruby-1.9.1-p243**) and the problem did not show up. Give that a try.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue on CentOS 5.6 with Ruby 1.9.3 and tried about a million things.  In the end, I installed apt-get on my CentOS machine and then ran:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

This upgraded the following packages (among others that weren't relevant):

```
libffi (3.0.5-1.el5 => 3.0.9-1.el5.rf)
libffi-devel (3.0.5-1.el5 => 3.0.9-1.el5.rf)
libyaml (0.1.2-3.el5 => 0.1.4-1.el5.rf)
libyaml-devel (0.1.2-3.el5 => 0.1.4-1.el5.rf)
```

that somehow fixed this.

I have no clue why or how, but it was definitely this that finally allowed the Ruby install to complete.

Answer (score 0):

Check for filesystem corruption.

Comment: I ran `sudo fsck -n` and had some minor errors. I'm keen to avoid taking down the server if possible and will need to organize downtime if I have to do this. I've posted the fsck output in my question - do you think this warrants a proper fsck?

Comment: I dunno, but I think this is a good question for superuser.com